# Ember.js models not being rendered in nested route

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an Ember app setup, and when visiting /playlist/1, it renders the templates as expected.  However, the model data isn't being displayed.  I have a playlist.hbs file with an outlet, and a playlist folder with index.hbs inside of that folder with html and handlebars to display data.  I have both App.PlaylistIndexController & App.PlaylistIndexRoute defined.

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('account', {path: '/account/:accountId'}, function() {
        this.route('login');
    });

    this.resource('playlist', { path: '/playlist/:playlist_id'}, function() {
        this.route('edit');
  });
});
```

FWIW, everything was working properly prior to adding the nested route (with my controller and route defined as App.PlaylistController and App.PlaylistRoute respectively)

```
"playlist":{"id":1,"name":"playlistname"}
```

Any ideas how to get the playlist data to display properly?

**UPDATE:**

```
App.PlaylistIndexRoute = App.AuthenticatedRoute.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this._super(controller, model);     
        var online = this.get('store').find('account');
        this.controllerFor('playlistViewers').set('model', online);
    },
});

<div id="main">
  <div id="primary">
    <section id="playlist">
      <header class="playlist-header">
        <h2>Playlist</h2>
        <h1>{{name}}</h1>       
      </header><!--.playlist-header-->

      <div class="playlist-content">
        <ul>

          {{#each song in songs}}
            <li {{action 'play' song}} class="show-for-mobile">
              <button {{bind-attr class="song.isPlaying:icon-volume-up:icon-play song.isStreaming:icon-adjust"}} ></button>
              <div class="song-meta"> 
                <span class="song-name">{{song.name}}</span>
                <span class="song-artist">{{song.artist}}</span>
              </div><!--.song-meta-->
            </li>
          {{/each}}
        </ul>       
      </div><!--.playlist-content-->
    </section><!--#playlist-->
  </div><!--#primary-->

{{partial "sidebar"}}
```

That's my current playlist/index.hbs file, but even {{name}} displays nothing

Comment: What do your App.PlaylistIndexRoute and playlist/index.hbs files look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `PlaylistIndexRoute` needs to have a model. This can be the model that was loaded by the playlist resource.

```
App.PlaylistIndexRoute = App.AuthenticatedRoute.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.modelFor('playlist');
  }
});
```

Comment: you're the best.  Do you know the reason why return this.get('store').find('playlist', params.account_id); doesn't work?

Comment: The params hash is only available to the resource with the dynamic segment. That's PlaylistRoute and not PlaylistIndexRoute. The Ember convention is to have PlaylistRoute load the model from the store, and then all of the PlaylistXXXRoute's can piggy back off that using modelFor.

Comment: OK, thanks for the help! That's a solid 'why' that the Ember docs just doesn't appear to answer